# "These many votes" on close dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons, tooltips, wording

I was reading the close dialog on a question that I had already voted to close. I put my cursor over the vote count and saw in the title attribute text: "these many votes already exist". Shouldn't this be "*this* many votes..."?

[image]

Comment: Depends on whether you want to put additional emphasis on *these* particular votes, I believe. Seriously, you're most probably right.

Comment: `n user(s) already cast votes using this close reason.`  The original tooltip is too vague and undescriptive.

Comment: @Robert, on the other hand there is a large blue `3` right behind that tooltip.

Answer (score 2):

No idea when this changed, but as of April 2016 that tooltip reads 'number of votes already cast', which feels like a slightly more grammatical description.

[image]

I feel it could probably still be improved a bit, but the current status is fine.